# How to use Qt5.7 with mingw on windows with bison 3.0.4 and flex

Tags: windows, qt, c++11, bison, mingw32

On windows I have installed qt with mingw 5.3. I downloaded here https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ (around 1.1 GB).

I need to compile flex and bison files. But there is no flex and bison installed. Then I downloaded https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/ it here and copied it to my c:/qt/bin/ folder. Flex is working fine. On the other hand bison is only the version 2.7 and my grammar makes errors...

I think the next steps would be to download the bison 3.0.4 tar ball  and compile it. But how to it without automake? to start ./configure? 
However, on sourceforge it is written the bison files are upgradable to 3.0. How do it?

Another approach would be I generate the bison flex on linux and compile it with mingw to get obj.o and then add it to qt project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find win_bison version 3.0 [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/win_flex_bison-2.5.6.zip/download)